# Узнать вес загружаемой картинки - php

Tags: php

Загружаю через это:

```
<?php

$icon = $_POST['img'];
$way = $_POST['way'];

if (preg_match('/^data:image\/(\w+);base64,/', $icon, $type)) {
    $icon = substr($icon, strpos($icon, ',') + 1);
    $type = strtolower($type[1]);

    if (!in_array($type, [ 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png' ])) {
        die('Invalid image type');
    }

    $icon = base64_decode($icon);

    if ($icon === false) {
        die('base64_decode failed');
    }
} else {
    die('Did not match data URI with image data');
}

$way = "{$way}.{$type}";

file_put_contents($way, $icon);
echo "success {$way}";

?>
```

Чтобы пользователи не загружали чересчур большие изображения, больше 1МБ, как узнать вес загружаемой картинки?

Comment: Для каких целей - это делается в обход `$_FILES`? Вообще не понимаю. на кой это делать через `$_POST`?

Comment: Не занимайтесь ерундой и юзайте `$_FILES` и `move_uploaded_file`, а для определения `mime` используйте например `finfo` класс. А не какие -то ручные проверки, формата, его можно подделать как пить дать.

Comment: @And У меня сервер на NodeJS отправляет картинку в виде base64, сам сервер получает его через socket,в котором передать файл нельзя (если и передаёт, то с ошибкой), поэтому такая реализация ;-;

Comment: Жесть, использовать сервер ноды и делать отправку на пых, мда уж...

Comment: @And по другому мне картинку не загрузить)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Способ выбран не самый лучший...

однозначно можно ответить - для определения размера сообщения достаточно посчитать количество байт в строке после декодирования из base64.

Таким образом, после строки `$icon = base64_decode($icon);` нужно вставить код:
`$image_size = strlen($icon);`

В переменной `$image_size` будет размер. По нему нужно делать условие. Размер - в байтах!

Дополнительно можно почитать про функцию [тут](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strlen.php).